# MERN project, too many API request, net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES, TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern

I'm working on a MERN project, I store many LEADS records in a MongoDB database. (LEADS-collection).
Now, I want to update the records of the collection with a new field called domain.
Updating the records works, however, I get an error after approx 1800 updates:
ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

I used Chrome and Edge as adviced in stackoverflow, however this does not change the outcome.

I use the following code to make the updates, all the information that I need
is stored in idAndDomain (ids+domainNames):

```
 const updateLeadsWithDomain = async () => {

      let newIdsAndDomains = [];

      for(let i=0; i<46000; i++) {

         newIdsAndDomains.push(idAndDomain[i])
      }


      await Promise.all(

        newIdsAndDomains.map(async (item) => {

          const response = updateLeads(item);
          console.log("Update domain successful")

        } )
      )

      updateLeads();
  }
```

updateLeads looks like this:

```
export const updateLeads = (items) => {


    console.log(items);

    return fetch(`${API}/leads/updateDomain`, {

        method:"PUT",
        headers: {

             Accept: 'application/json',
              "Content-Type": "application/json"            
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(items)

    }).then(res => {

         return res.json();

    }).catch(error => {

        console.log(error);
    })
```

server:

```
     router.put("/leads/updateDomain",updateDomain);

      .......

     exports.updateDomain = (req,res) => {
 

          console.log(req.body.id)

        Lead.findOneAndUpdate(         

        {_id: req.body.id}, 

        {$set: req.body}, 
        {new: true}, 
        (err,user) => {

            if(err) {
           
                console.log(err)

        }
           
             res.json(user);

        }  
      )
    }
```

How can I fix that? Can I give the browser more time to process this? Is there an alternative to this API-loop? (Downlading all the records takes about 3 seconds, no error)
-- This application is NOT for public use.

Answer (score 0):

I made everything on mongodb itself, no API requests involved.
First of all, I duplicate the email field then I modify the string of the new "domain" field - very easy!

duplicate email:

```
db.leads.update (
 {},
 [ {
    $set: {  domain: "$email" } ,
 ],
 { multi: true}
  );
```

update is deprecated but I don't care about this right now.

modify the string in the new field "domain":

```
db.leads.aggregate([
 {$project: 
  {
     firstname:1,
     lastname:1, email:1, phone:1, tdl:1,__v:1, createdAt:1, updatedAt:1,
     domain:{$arrayElemAt:[{$split:["$domain", "@"]}, 1]}
  }
 },
{$out:"leads"}
]);
```